# Control Name's in XAML WIndows Phone 8.1 Runtime dont show in CS File

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm trying to create a grid in my Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime Project, and everytime i nominate the control, it doesn't recognized in CS file, like:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Height="1168" Width="386" >
```

How can i fix that, its is a bug, or some class is not in CS using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason might be that you are refering to it before calling `InitializeComponent()`
 method.

Comment: look thoses photos here is CS file http://www.tickimg.com.br/uploads/_img1.jpg 
Here the XAML file 
http://www.tickimg.com.br/uploads/_img2.jpg
I put after InitializeComponent() method!

Comment: I still can't see exactly what are you trying to acomplish in your program, however try moving scrollviewer into grid. It might be omitted/treated as useless code.

Comment: also try cleaning and building your code again. Make sure you are editing right xaml file.

Comment: Thanks, it works! i never had this problem before, i always did the same way untill now, thanks for you helpping!

Comment: If you find my answer helpfull, please mark it as usefull and accepted asnwer. Have a nice day bro.